# Set Handling Time and Inventory update

Tags: amazon-mws

I was wondering if there is any way to set the Handling Time with Inventory update.

We are having the issue, when changing the quantity, the RestockDate & Handling Times fields are reset to being empty for that item. After reading through documentation, I understand this is the way MWS works.

We use the `_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_` feedtype when updating inventory.

Is there any way or report to retrieve those 2 fields or  to to add Handling time with Inventory update service of feedtype `_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_`.

Answer (score 8):

In Amazon's XML terminology, the handling time is called FulfillmentLatency:

> FulfillmentLatency - The number of days between the order date and the ship date (a whole number between 1 and 30).

The following XML snippet shows where that information fits in.

```
<Inventory>
<SKU>MyProductCode</SKU>
<Quantity>100</Quantity>
<FulfillmentLatency>3</FulfillmentLatency>
</Inventory>
```

Assuming you already have the rest of the feed up and running and are not getting any errors, the addition of FulfillmentLatency in your XML feed should take care of your problem.

This and further info on the Amazon MWS API XML formats can be found in the [Selling on Amazon
Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V397584891_.pdf)